# django oracle setup throws error

Tags: python, django, oracle

oracle_home is mandatory while setting django with oracle, i have two machine in one ip address Oracle is installed and in other Ip address setting up django webapp, when i try to install

```
pip install cx_Oracle
```

it throws error

```
 pip install cx_Oracle
Downloading/unpacking cx-Oracle
  Running setup.py egg_info for package cx-Oracle
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-root/cx-Oracle/setup.py", line 135, in <module>
        raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \
    distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/cx-Oracle/setup.py", line 135, in <module>

    raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \

distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation
```

**Is it must to installed Oracle in the same box**  or I'm missing soething here

Comment: Yes cx_oracle needs the Oracle libraries. Have you set ORACLE_HOME to point to your oracle installation before pip install? You also need the Oracle Client SDK.

Comment: @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe The setup is Linux,Python2.7 and django=1.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
pip install cx_oracle
```

Comment: taht works thanks, i just need to check is there any way we can avoid oracle installation and can work with the .lib files

Comment: Download oracle instantclient files (basic and sdk). Extract them to a temp directory. Set ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to these files. Do pip install. After this you can remove instantclient files. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html